# Powershell script to search text file and output multiple lines in order

Tags: powershell

My source file has multiple serial interfaces.  I want to simply output each serial line "Serial0/2/0:0" and then the following drops, aborts, etc. on the next lines in the output file under each Serial interface.  So far I have this:

```
get-childitem show-int.log | select-string -pattern drops | foreach {$_.line}
```

And simply run it with > todays-date.  I am a network engineer so forgive how bad I am at ps.  I've tried google and putting the many items in quotes but nothing works to my satisfaction.

> Serial0/2/0:0 is up, line protocol is up
>
> Hardware is DSX1
>
> MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1536 Kbit/sec, DLY 20000 usec,
>
> reliability 255/255, txload 33/255, rxload 133/255
>
> Encapsulation PPP, LCP Open, multilink Open
>
> Link is a member of Multilink bundle Multilink1, loopback not set
>
> Keepalive set (10 sec)
>
> Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never
>
> Last clearing of "show interface" counters 1d18h
>
> Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops:
>   381
>
> Queueing strategy: fifo
>
> Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
>
> 5 minute input rate 805000 bits/sec, 188 packets/sec
>
> 5 minute output rate 200000 bits/sec, 153 packets/sec
>
> 8320454 packets input, 2999426407 bytes, 0 no buffer
>
> Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
>
> ```
>  22 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles 
>
>  30 input errors, 29 CRC, 0 frame, 1 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
>
>  7629921 packets output, 1268811436 bytes, 0 underruns
>
>  0 output errors, 0 collisions, 4294967295 interface resets
>
>  0 unknown protocol drops
>
>  0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
>
>  7 carrier transitions
> ```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Please add an example of what the input file looks like, and what you want your output to be.

Comment: I just edited my comment with the input text but it looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Not precise, but easy:

```
Get-Content show-int.log | select-string 'Serial0/2/0:0' -Context 0,10
```

Comment: Works!  However, I want it to output, say, the 3rd line under "Serial0/2/0:0" and not the first two lines before that.  And then output the 9th line next.  I've tried "-Content 3" and so forth but that makes it output the 3 lines above "Serial0/2/0:0" and then 3 after.

Comment: Yes, -Context is just to display the surrounding lines. If you want more precise control, you need to create something more complex. It wasn't clear from your question if that's really required.

Comment: Ok.  I apologize.  I have now learned about -Context at least.